# reverse preg_replace in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to delete `\DIFadd{` and last `}` (i.e.`}` before `\DIFadd{`) for example 
`This is a string with} }df} some text\DIFadd{` and output should be 
`This is a string with} }df some text`

```
$str='\DIFaddbegin \begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}\\
y_{3}}\\\DIFadd{
e_{5}
\end{pmatrix}}\\
\DIFadd{\mathbf{y}\quad }&\DIFadd{= \quad \mathbf{\tau} \ \quad \mathbf{e}.
}\end{align*}';
```

Expected output:

```
\DIFaddbegin \begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}\\
y_{3}\\
e_{5}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\mathbf{y}\quad &= \quad \mathbf{\tau} \ \quad \mathbf{e}.
}\end{align*}
```

So,how to preg_replace from backwards so that I can replace the string `}` and `\DIFadd{` 
I tried,
`$str=preg_replace('/}(.*?)\\\\DIFadd{/',"$1",$str);//but its not getting last }`

Comment: Try with negated `[^}]*` instead of `.*?` `$str = preg_replace('/}([^}]*)\\\DIFadd{/', "$1", $str);`

Comment: Ya, This works fine. I thought this would be a complicated pattern as I need like reversed order pattern. It dint strike me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need a recursive pattern to find the good closing curly bracket:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\\\DIFadd{([^{}]*(?:{(?1)}[^{}]*)*+)}~', '$1', $str);
```

details:

```
~
\\\DIFadd{
(                   # capture group 1
    [^{}]*          # all that is not a bracket
    (?:             # eventually followed by an opening bracket
        { (?1) }    # (?1) refers to the subpattern of capture group 1
        [^{}]*
    )*+
)
}
~
```

Since `(?1)` is called inside itself (the capture group 1), it's a recursion.

Note: if you have nested `\DIFadd{...}`, you must put the replacement in a `do..while` loop and use `preg_replace` count parameter:

```
do {
    $str = preg_replace('~\\\DIFadd{([^{}]*(?:{(?1)}[^{}]*)*+)}~', '$1', $str, -1, $count);
} while ($count);
```

Comment: if this is the string `caregivers, \tex}t}it\DIFadd{sometext}} such as extended'` i should get output like `'caregivers, \tex}titsometext}} such as extended'` but it outputs `caregivers, \tex}t}itsometext} such as extended` its deleting `}` after `\DIFadd{` but  I want to delete `}` which is before `\DIFadd{`

Answer (score 0):

```
$text="
Pa pa pa pa -
Papa oom ma mow mow
Papa oom mow mow
Pa pa pa oom ma ma ma mow
Papa oom mow mow
";

$text = explode(' ', $text);
$text = array_reverse($text);
$text = implode(' ', $text);
$text = preg_replace('%mow%i','',$text,2);
$text = explode(' ', $text);
$text = array_reverse($text);
$text = implode(' ', $text);

echo $text;
```

**BEFORE:**

> ```
> Pa pa pa pa -
> Papa oom ma mow mow
> Papa oom mow mow
> Pa pa pa oom ma ma ma mow
> Papa oom mow mow
> ```

**AFTER:**

> ```
> Pa pa pa pa -
> Papa oom ma mow mow
> Papa oom mow mow
> Pa pa pa oom ma ma ma mow
> Papa oom
> ```